# How to syncronyze rabbitmq messages?

Tags: python, rest, go, rabbitmq, microservices

I have an application(APP), and now i need to integrate with some service(SERVICE-1) which supports communication through rabbitmq(sending request to one queue and listen for response in another one), i decided to move all the rabbitmq part to separate service(SERVICE-2) and communicate with it through REST api calls.

The problem is - in APP i need a synchronous response to my call, so SERVICE-2 need somehow to synchronize those request:
like it needs to get a HTTP request -> send request to rabbitmq -> wait for response from rabbitmq -> give HTTP response back in a single HTTP session.

But responses in rabbitmq may be in other order, for example i send requests with id 1,2,3 and receive back them in order 3,1,2

Comment: Take a look at the [RPC feature of RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html).

Comment: If you need a synchronous response, you'll need a callback queue for each request. It's messy, but it's the only way. 

The real question is if you really need synchronous responses. If you need to tie it to the HTTP request, and you are willing to keep the HTTP client waiting for the response, why are you even using rabbitmq and separate consumers? Just keep it all on the HTTP service.